# How to fix the number of CPUs used by MemSQL?

Tags: singlestore

I am running MemSQL(1 agg and 5 leaf nodes) on a single box which has 2 TB of RAM.

However this is a shared system and there are other processes running on it. When I deploy the cluster and run few queries, the CPU utilization goes really high and looks like it uses all the cores. Is there a way I can prevent this happening by specifying the number of cores to use?

I checked the documents and there is a paramter called `maximum_memory` which is set by default to 90% of the host memory. Is this the parameter that needs to be changed?

Comment: I changed it to 10% from 90% and the CPU utilization reduced significantly.  So the number of cores are driven by the amount of memory allocated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MemSQL configuration option to limit the number of cores. The cpu utilization decrease you observed from reducing your `maximum_memory` is indicative of the system using less machine resources overall (you reduced memory availablilty to the system by 80%).

If you want to limit the number of CPUs being used by MemSQL, use [taskset](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html).

Comment: actually reducing the memory reduced the CPU utilization, but during data load from spark, it shot up again. so reducing maximum_memory does not help much.

Comment: I used taskset and assigned 2 cores to each memsqld process. like `taskset -cp 0,1 <process_id_of_memsqld> `But that does not seem to be working. On query it is taking all the cores at 100 % utilization.

Comment: `taskset` command was done incorrectly. now it is working, this is the command i tried
`taskset -p -c <cpu_number> <pid>`